# The definition of operator $T$ is said to be invertible

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> In Folland's textbook. If $T\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{X})$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is a Banach space, $T$ is said to be invertible, if $T$ is nijective and $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

My question is that why the definition is not there exists $S$ such that $TS=I$ and $ST=I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the normed linear space $X$ is complete then the two definitions are equivalent, by Open Mapping Theorem. Otherwise your  definition is weaker and it does not guarantee that $S=T^{-1}$ is a bounded operator from $X \to X$. In other words $S$ need not belong to  $L(X,X)$.

For a specific example let $X$ be  the space of all sequences $(a_n)$ of real numbers which have only finite number of non-zero terms at most. Define $\|(a_n)\|=\sum_n |a_n|$  Let $T(a_n)=(\frac  1n a_n)$. Then Let $S(a_n)=(na_n)$. Then $ST=TS=I$  and $T$ is bounded but $S$ is not.

Comment: Wouldn't the right shift on, say, $\ell^2$ be a counterexample to them being equivalent?

Comment: NO. The right shift and left shift are inverses only in one direction. $(a_n) \to (0,a_1,a_2,...0)$ is not surjective., so it cannot have a two-sided inverse. @Jose27

Comment: Right. But how does surjective follow from Folland's definition? Or is it a convention thing?

Comment: @Jose27 There is a typo in the qutation from Folland's book. What is typed as 'nijective' is supposed to be 'bijective' not 'injective'.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!